# Bluetooth doesn't start up properly when I start up

Tags: bluetooth

Basically, Bluetooth via my USB dongle doesn't work until after I manually `/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` a few times. Is there a way to have it start automagically so I don't have to do this each and every boot?

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Startup Applications** and make sure that Bluetooth Manager is enabled.

[image]

Comment: It is. What's really weird is that I must show Bluetooth Preferences (the manager) and _then_ `/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` in order for things to work. Weird.

Answer (score -1):

you can but this command in the startup application choose add new and put this in the command filed.
[image]

Comment: A blank command, really? Not helpful at all, thanks for the sarcasm though.

Comment: not a blank command put your command in the box or put it in .sh file and click browse then  add the file .

Comment: Gotcha. Nevermind then, I can do this myself, I suppose, in an `/etc/init` script.

Comment: Hi TK Kocheran. Can you please post your solution? I'm new to Ubuntu and I have the same problem -- Bluetooth is not active after reboot.